Gradle project sinc failed: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'
I encounter the following error when making a new project in Android Studio. What is the possible solution?


A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Failed to transform signflinger-8.4.0.jar (com.android:signflinger:8.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.internal.hierarchy-collected=false, org.gradle.internal.instrumented=instrumented-external-dependency, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Could not find signflinger-8.4.0.jar (com.android:signflinger:8.4.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/8.4.0/signflinger-8.4.0.jar
Failed to transform zipflinger-8.4.0.jar (com.android:zipflinger:8.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.internal.hierarchy-collected=false, org.gradle.internal.instrumented=instrumented-external-dependency, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Could not find zipflinger-8.4.0.jar (com.android:zipflinger:8.4.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/8.4.0/zipflinger-8.4.0.jar
Failed to transform annotations-31.4.0.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:31.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.internal.hierarchy-collected=false, org.gradle.internal.instrumented=instrumented-external-dependency, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Could not find annotations-31.4.0.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:31.4.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/31.4.0/annotations-31.4.0.jar
Failed to transform apksig-8.4.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:8.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.internal.hierarchy-collected=false, org.gradle.internal.instrumented=instrumented-external-dependency, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Could not find apksig-8.4.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:8.4.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/8.4.0/apksig-8.4.0.jar


Possible solution:

Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html


